# matplotlib and ggplot - face_grid text size label

Tags: python, matplotlib, ggplot2, python-ggplot

I am using `ggplot`'s facet_grid function on `date`.

```
p = ggplot(aes(x='meh',weight='mah',fill='type'),data=plot_df) + geom_bar(stat='identity') + facet_grid('date',scales='fixed') + ggtitle(title)
```

I am using the following arguments to edit the legend and axis sizes succesfully:

```
t = theme_gray()
t._rcParams['font.size'] = 30 # Legend font size
t._rcParams['xtick.labelsize'] = 30 # xaxis tick label size
t._rcParams['ytick.labelsize'] = 30 # yaxis tick label size
t._rcParams['axes.labelsize'] = 30 # general label size 

p = p + t
```

[image]

As you can see from the attached image, the right labels (`date`) are barely legible.

Which of the matplotlib arguments controls this label text size? I can see the custom options for matplotlib [here](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html) but since the `facet_grid` is a `ggplot` function I cannot see which of these controls this particular label.

## Edit

Sample [input](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dypsshvuqm6wvim/tmp.csv?dl=0):

```
import pandas as pd
from ggplot import *

data_df = pd.read_csv("/dir/sample/input/above/tmp.csv")

print data_df.head()

p = ggplot(aes(x='status',weight='duration_proportion',fill='line_name'),data=data_df) + geom_bar(stat='identity') + labs(x="Service status", y="Percentage time") + facet_grid('date',scales='fixed')

t = theme_gray()

t._rcParams['font.size'] = 30 # Legend font size
t._rcParams['xtick.labelsize'] = 30 # xaxis tick label size
t._rcParams['ytick.labelsize'] = 30 # yaxis tick label size
t._rcParams['axes.labelsize'] = 30 

p = p + t

p.save("test.png" ,height=24,width=44)
```

Comment: thank you @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I've added a sample file (I found it too difficult to autogenerate one) and steps to reproduce. :)

Comment: I tried obtaining a figure handle, but that seems impossible. `plt.gcf()` does not return the ggplot facet grid figure. Neither does `fig, (ax, ax2) = p.make_facets()` work. Maybe someone else has an idea.

Comment: Thank you for trying @ImportanceOfBeingErnest.